# Android WebView will only load the first URL that is passed to it on all calls to loadUrl() thereafter

Tags: javascript, android, webview

The onCreate():

```
    private WebView mWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");


    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://yahoo.com/");
}
```

Now as you can see we have a Javascript Interface. We use this to call a function on the page that calls a function on the WebView which is here:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    private Activity activity;

    public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void doareload(){
        //mWebView.clearCache(true);
        //mWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.ca/");
    }
}
```

And in the Javascript on the page:

```
function tryWebViewReload() {
  window.JSInterface.doareload();
  return;
}
```

The method does get called in the Java code, but no matter what call we do it will ONLY reload yahoo.com (or whatever the first URL passed to the WebView is).

Please let me know if additional information would be helpful.

Comment: Still haven't figured this one out :(